# What are the advantages and disadvantages between these coding styles?

Tags: options, key-value

Some people use the following style

```
setting
{
     a=1
    ,b=2
    ,c=3    
}
```

and the other ones use the style below

```
setting
{
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3 
}
```

I use the latter style but I wonder why some people prefer the former style?
Is there anything I missed?

Comment: That's interesting.  Though there are many bracing and whitespacing conventions around I haven't seen that comma convention before.

Comment: @Matthew: The first comma convention is very common in Haskell.

Comment: In (La)TeX I tend to use the first variant, because then I don't forget adding it if I add additional keys (if I edit code by others with the second convention this regularly happens to me), can comment out any line (if I comment out the first it takes a slight performance hit), and don't have a performance hit that I'd get from putting a comma at the end of each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ConTeXt, the two are not equivalent. The former sets `a` to be `1\n` etc. This leads to a very common beginner error:

```
\setupsomething
    [...]
    [ key1=value,
      key2=value,
      key3=value
    ]
```

Notice that the last line does not contain a comma, so `key3` is set to be equal `value\n`. To avoid that use

```
\setupsomething
    [...]
    [ key1=value,
      key2=value,
      key3=value,
    ]
```

or

```
\setupsomething
    [...]
    [ key1=value,
      key2=value,
      key3=value]
```

Comment: +1 for introducing ConTeXt, I am interested in it recently.

Answer (score 5):

Usually when setting keys you can do it this way:

```
{
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
}
```

Then all rows can be commented out and additional rows can be inserted anywhere.

Comment: The last row is allowed to have a trailing comma? Are you sure?

Comment: Yep, I use this in my PGFplots to comment/uncomment sections and not have to worry if I need to add or remove a comma. Very useful.

Comment: In fact, `\pgfkeys` just ignores empty keys in its argument, so you can have as many superfluous commas as you like.  Marginally useful when constructing argument lists from optional user input.

Comment: +1 for confirming the trailing comma.

Comment: Another good example pertaining to superfluous commas, visit [Does this compile?](http://statestreetgang.net/post/2009/02/Does-this-compile.aspx#comment)